# how to tell a python type checker that an optional definitely exists?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pyright

I'm used to typescript, in which one can use a `!` to tell the type-checker to assume a value won't be null. Is there something analogous when using type annotations in python?

A (contrived) example:

When executing the expression `m.maybe_num + 3` in the code below, the enclosing `if` guarantees that `maybe_num` won't be `None`.  But the type-checker doesn't know that, and returns an error.  (Verified in https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10.) How can I tell the type-checker that I know better?

```py
from typing import Optional

class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, maybe_num: Optional[int]):
        self.maybe_num = maybe_num
        
    def has_a_num(self) -> bool:
        return self.maybe_num is not None

    def three_more(self) -> Optional[int]:
        if self.has_a_num:
            # mypy error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")
            return self.maybe_num + 3
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: @MrBeanBremen the TypeGuard annotation can be used to get methods to be parsed like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there's no clean way to infer the type of something from a function call like this, but you can work some magic with [`TypeGuard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard) annotations for the `has_a_num()` method, although the benefit from those annotations won't really be felt unless the difference is significantly more major than the type of a single int. If it's just a single value, you should just use a standard  is not None check.

```py
if self.maybe_num is not None:
    ...
```

You can define a subclass of your primary subclass, where the types of any parameters whose types are affected are explicitly redeclared.

```py
class MyIntClass(MyClass):
    maybe_num: int
```

From there, your checker function should still return a boolean, but the annotated return type tells MyPy that it should use it for type narrowing to the listed type.

Sadly it will only do this for proper function parameters, rather than the implicit `self` argument, but this can be fixed easily enough by providing self explicitly as follows:

```py
if MyClass.has_a_num(self):
    ...
```

That syntax is yucky, but it works with MyPy.

This makes the full solution be as follows

```py
# Parse type annotations as strings to avoid 
# circular class references
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional, TypeGuard

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, maybe_num: Optional[int]):
        self.maybe_num = maybe_num

    def has_a_num(self) -> TypeGuard[_MyClass_Int]:
        # This annotation defines a type-narrowing operation,
        # such that if the return value is True, then self
        # is (from MyPy's perspective) _MyClass_Int, and 
        # otherwise it isn't
        return self.maybe_num is not None

    def three_more(self) -> Optional[int]:
        if MyClass.has_a_num(self):
            # No more mypy error
            return self.maybe_num + 3
        else:
            return None

class _MyClass_Int(MyClass):
    maybe_num: int
```

`TypeGuard` was added in Python 3.10, but can be used in earlier versions using the [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module from `pip`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I've edited it now and it works - it's a little more complex, but it is absolutely worthwhile for more complex classes where a single checker function performs a lot of type narrowing on many types (which is implied by the existence of the function rather than a simple if statement).

Comment: @brahn let me know if this solves your problem!

Comment: Works great!  FWIW, in the mypy sandbox running python 3.10 I still had to import `TypeGuard` from `typing extensions`.  It is, as you say, a bit awkward but good to have this tool in my toolkit.